# Algorithm for max distance in elements

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I have found a solution that you find the max and min element in the array which can be done by one loop and will take only n number of runs and then subtract them to find the max distance.
Is my solution right??
Is there any better solution than this??

Comment: Yes, your solution is great, but it is for an entirely different problem: you are looking for the max difference, while they are looking for a min difference.

Comment: How should anyone be able to rate your improvements when you do not post the (pseudo-)code for it?

Comment: are the elements sorted?

Comment: an easy way to do it, 1- use quick sort to sort the elements, 2- the min distance is A[1] - A[0] but make sure that the elements should be at least 2 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maximum Distance

For **maximum** distance your solution is right. There is no better solution as you **must** go over all elements in the array. Time complexity will be `O(n)`.

Pseudo-Code:

```
MaxDistance(A)
    min = max = A[0]
    for i=1 to n-1
        if A[i] < min
            min = A[i]
        if A[i] > max
            max = A[i]
    return (max-min)
```

### Minimum Distance

The pseudo code in your question is for finding the **minimum** distance between any pair in the array. A more efficient solution would be:

1. Sort the array `A` in ascending order. `O(nlogn)`
2. Iterate over the sorted array and compare all adjacent pairs while keeping track of the minimum distance. `O(n)`

Pseudo-Code:

```
MinDistance(A)
    sort(A)
    min_dist = infinity
    for i=1 to n-1
        dist = A[i]-A[i-1]
        if (min_dist > dist)
            min_dist = dist
    return min_dist
```

Total time complexity: `O(nlogn)`